# Intersection of Two Lists Objects in java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream, intersect

An intersection of Two Lists Objects in java 8. Can some tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
List<Student> originalStudent = new ArrayList<>();
List<Student> newStudent = new ArrayList<>();

List<Student> intersectListStudent = new LinkedList<>()

originalStudent.add(new Student("William", "Tyndale",1));
originalStudent.add(new Student("Jonathan", "Edwards",2));
originalStudent.add(new Student("Martin", "Luther"),3);

newStudent.add(new Student("Jonathan", "Edwards",2));
newStudent.add(new Student("James", "Tyndale",4));
newStudent.add(new Student("Roger", "Moore",5));


originalStudent.forEach(n ->
        newStudent.stream()
                .filter(db -> !n.getName().equals(db.getName()) &&
                        !n.getLastName().equals(db.getLastName()))
                    .forEach(student-> intersectListStudent .add(student)));
```

Comment: what is the output that you're expecting? what is that you think is wrong? that's not self explanatory by the way

Comment: Since a `List` can contain the same element multiple times, when you intersect the lists, if A has element `x` three times, and B has element `x` twice times, how many times do you expect the answer in the final list?  3? 2? 1? This will determine which of these approaches works.

Answer (score 15):

> Can some tell me what am I doing wrong?

You violate the [*Side-effects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) principle of [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) which in a nutshell says that a stream shouldn't modify another collection while performing the actions through the pipelines. I haven't tested your code, however, this is not a way you should treat streams.

---

**How to do it better?**

Simply use the [`List::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) in the filter's predicate to get rid of the unique values.

```
List<Student> students = originalStudent.stream()
                                        .filter(newStudent::contains)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This solution (understand the method [`List::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)) is based on the implemented equality comparison using [`Object::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Hence, there is needed to override the very same method in the class `Student`.

Edit: Please, be aware that that automatically overriding the `Object::equals` will mind the `id` to the equality computation. Therefore the equality will be based on the name and surname only. (thanks to [@nullpointer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746118/nullpointer)).

**Without the `Object::equals` overridden?**

You have to perform the comparison in the `filter` using another `stream` and the method `Stream::anyMatch` which returns `true` if the predicate is qualified.

```
List<Student> students = originalStudent.stream()
              .filter(os -> newStudent.stream()                    // filter
                  .anyMatch(ns ->                                  // compare both
                       os.getName().equals(ns.getName() &&         // name
                       os.getLastName().equals(ns.getLastName()))) // last name
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this would definitely need an object comparison. also the fact that is the last attribute value changes in the two sample lists provided, the output would vary here from what is expected in the question.

Comment: I meant, if I change `originalStudent.add(new Student("Jonathan", "Edwards",2));` to `originalStudent.add(new Student("Jonathan", "Edwards",7));`, you first code block wouldn't provide same output as your latter suggestion.

Comment: Plus one for the solution with `anyMatch` and `collect` :)

Comment: @Myjay1516, why is this not the accepted answer? :/

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is construct a `SortedSet<Student>` from the two concatenated lists `originalStudent` and `newStudent`. The sorted set uses a `Comparator.comparing(Student::getName).thenComparing(Student::getLastName)` as its comparator.

```
Stream.concat(originalStudent.stream(), newStudent.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(
        Comparator.comparing(Student::getFname)
            .thenComparing(Student::getLname))
    ))
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Thank you!... Those who are working with list you have to convert treeset to list. _new ArrayList<Student>(treeSetListVariable)_